# Bootstrap carousel collapsing between slides once page has loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have just finished this site but am having problems with the carousel and cannot figure out why. Upon loading the carousel works fine but then i starts collapsing between slides. This is happening on all pages.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to the site  http://www.moulin.jimgbestphotography.co.uk

Thanks again

Comment: Seems to look fine in Chrome

Comment: Yeah it seems so until you hover or click on something. I have various other bootstrap jquery bits on each page. But still cant find the conflict. Thanks though.

Comment: Not to worry worked around another way. Cheers ]